# Can I call a modal popup extender's (which is in one user control) show method from other user control?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls, modalpopupextender

I have two user controls. One is having a `ModalPopupExtender` which I need to show on a click 
 of hyperlink button which is other user control.

Is it possible? Can I anyhow call a modal popup extender's `Show()` method from other user control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it solved!

```
AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender mpe = ((AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender)(Page.Master.FindControl("usercontrol1").FindControl("ModalPopupExtenderLoginStatus")));
                if (mpe != null)
                {
                    mpe.Show();
                }
```

Comment: Hi - an anonymous user tried to edit this to ask for a fuller code sample so he could better understand your solution. Is there anything else necessary or is this code snippet enough?

Comment: It worked for me so I think it's enough and gives an idea what needs to be done.